# Storing dictionary data using Python3 and SQLlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Here is my code:

```
def getDownloaders(dbPATH):
 with sqlite3.connect(dbPATH) as db:
      cursor = db.cursor()
      cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Downloaders")
      d = cursor.fetchall()

      downloader = {}
      column_names = [s[0] for s in cursor.description]

      for i in range(len(d)):
        for row in d:
            downloader[i] = dict(zip(column_names, row))

 print(downloader)
 return downloader
```

Here is my data:

```
[{1, 'lll', ‘lll', 'lll', '', ‘1’,  'lobio', 'c:/'},
{2, 'test', ‘test3', 'blob', 'blah', ‘1’,  'lio', 'c:/'},
{3, 'ledere', ‘copsssss', 'reds', 'server', ‘0’,  'lobio', 'c:/'}]
```

Here is what I want in a dictionary

```
{0: {'id': 1, 'Host': 'lll', 'username': 'lll', 'password': 'lll', 'label': 'lll', 'Enabled': 1, 'name': 'lobio', 'file': 'c:/'}, 1: {'id': 2,'Host': 'test', 'username': 'test3', 'password': 'blob', 'label': 'blah', 'Enabled': 1, 'name': 'lio', 'file': 'c:/'}, 2: {'id': 3, 'Host': 'lwderel', 'username': ‘copsssss', 'password': 'reds', 'label': 'server', 'Enabled': 0, 'name': 'lobio', 'file': 'c:/'}}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

You have two nested `for` loops, for all row indexes, and for all rows, so the innermost line sees all combinations of `i` and `row` (3×3), even those where these two do not match.

You have to use a single loop:

```
cursor.execute("...")
column_names = [s[0] for s in cursor.description]
downloader = {}
i = 0
for row in cursor:
  downloader[i] = dict(zip(column_names, row))
  i += 1
```

And a dictionary with consecutive numbers as keys is pointless; it would be simpler to use an array as return value:

```
cursor.execute("...")
column_names = [s[0] for s in cursor.description]
downloader = [dict(zip(column_names, row)) for row in cursor]
```